# Best way to hide parent item title if there are no grandchild items in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have data from graphql as

```
resources {
    publications {
        books {
            book 1
            book 2
        }
        brochures {
            brochures 1
            brochures 2
        }
    }
}
```

I need to present obtained data as

Resources
Publications
Books
1. Book 1
2. Book 2
Brochures
1. Brochure 1
2. Brochure 2

If there are no books and brochures I do not want to show Resources and Publication.

I have so far done is like this

```
{resources.publications.book || resources.publications.brochures ? (
                      <p>
                        Resources
                      </p>
                    ) : null}

{resources.publications.book || resources.publications.brochures ? (
                  <p>
                    Publications
                  </p>
                ) : null}
```

{resources.publications.books && (

Books

)}

I am willing to know if there are better ways to hide resources and publications if there are no items under books and brochures categories.

Answer (score 0):

I think It's a better way that you have to use like that

```
{resources.publications.book && (
                      <p>
                        Resources
                      </p>)}

{resources.publications.brochures && (
                  <p>
                    Publications
                  </p>
                )}
```

Because why we have two times to check for the display. if **Books** then we have to only check **resources.publications.book** and if **brouchers** the we have to only check **resources.publications.brochures**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constant that ensure that publications attributes has any value or key with [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method or use a library like [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#some):

```
const hasPublications = Object.keys(resources.publications).some(publication => {
    return Object.keys(resources.publications[publication]).length;
  });


{hasPublications && (
 <React.Fragment>
  <p>Resources</p>
  <p>Publications</p>
 </React.Fragment>
)}
```

OR

```
{hasPublications && (<p>Resources</p>)}
{hasPublications && (<p>Publications</p>)}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is for `book or brochures`:

```
{(resources.publications.book || resources.publications.brochures) && (
  <p>
    Publications
  </p>
)}
```

and this is for `book and brochures`:

```
{(resources.publications.book && resources.publications.brochures) && (
  <p>
    Publications
  </p>
)}
```